# Writing front end gui for commandline application

Tags: c++, user-interface, command-line, cross-platform, wrapper

Can anyone please, point out some good tutorials, to develop a front end gui for commandline applications ? I mean writing a front end for applications like ffmpeg,nmap etc. I know that there exists many for these applications but I really need to know how to do it?. I'm planning to develop gui for some c++ applications? . What would be the better methods for doing it and what libraries for gui development should be used to ensure cross-platform functionality ? Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: First of all thank you all for your help. I have another question about this. Does executing commandline applications handling their arguments result in reduction of performance of the application? I mean do i need to use threads for this one? Are there any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping command line applications usually means executing the command line application, handling their command line parameters, and parsing their output.

For a GUI toolkit I would suggest going for one of the major cross platform toolkits:

- Qt (C++)
- GTK+ (C, has C++ wrapper called gtkmm)
- wxWidgets (C++)